# What is the use of the 'は' particle in this sentence?

Tags: particles

The sentence is 'あなたには僕が見えるか？', which supposedly translates to 'Can you see me?'.

I'm confused about the usage of the ’は’ particle here. Since there is already the ’が’ particle to indicate that 僕 is the subject and the ’に’ particle to indicate that あなた is the passive agent, what is the use of the ’は’ particle?

*The sentence is taken from the lyrics of the song 'Unknown Mother Goose'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This は is a topic marker. A topic and a subject are related but different concepts in Japanese, and "double subject" sentences are not uncommon (see [this](https://eastasiastudent.net/study/topic-prominent/)).

Here are two sentences where different words are topicalized. Both sentences translate as "Can you see me?" (or "Am I visible to you?") into idiomatic English, but I added super-literal translations to show the difference.

> あなたには僕が見えるか？
> *As for you*, am I visible?
>
> 僕はあなたに見えるか？
> *As for me*, (am I) visible to you?